# D7 : Plupload version could not be determined

Tags: files

I have installed the Plupload module and downloaded the library files v1.5.8.

I then uploaded the 'js' folder to '/sites/all/libraries/plupload/'

Having done so, 'admin/reports/status' now returns a message saying 'Plupload version could not be determined.'

Have I missed something obvious?

- I have also tried the same with the latest v2.1.1 , with the same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok.

The problem was that i never uploaded the changelog.txt along with the js folder.

Comment: thx, unfortunately the 2.x versions have no changelog.txt with them, I tried to fake one but no luck, so I use 1.5.8 now. just fyi

Comment: Correct, i spotted that it states on the plupload integration module page that 2.x isn't supported at all yet so likewise, i'm using 1.5.8

Comment: ok i see, thx for confirmation!